# excel file is being downloaded on the server not on the client

Tags: c#, .net, export-to-excel

I have a button on my web app to export an Excel file but when the user clicks the button, my mistake is that I am downloading the document on the server, not on the client. This is my code:

```
var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
String f = excelApp.GetSaveAsFilename(nameOfDocument, "Excel Filter (*.xlsx), *.xlsx").ToString();
workSheet.SaveAs(f);
```

I am using Office Interop Excel.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use Interop on your asp.net server. [Microsoft discourages that since it can lead to undesired behavior.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757)

Second, you should save the document, and output it to the response stream. One way to do that is using [`TransmitFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// save your file to a temporary location
string pathToTheSavedFile = ...;

// then transmit the file
HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(pathToTheSavedFile);
```

Comment: in that case, how can i save it please to a temporary location?

Comment: What about [`Path.GetTempPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: your code gives me exception states that the file is not there, it shows me the path of the file, and i can see the file is there, i run vs on administrator mode

Comment: I will ask a separate question

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. What line is causing the issue?